# Which model should i use for tensorflow (contrib or models)?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, resnet, tensorflow-model-analysis

For example if i want to use renset_v2, there are two model file on tensorflow:

one is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/resnet_v2.py), another is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/nets/resnet_v2.py). Lots of tensorflow model are both in [models/research](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets) and [tensorflow/contrib](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/nets).

I am very confused: which model is better? which model should i use?

Answer (score 2):

In general, `tf.contrib` contains contributed code mostly by the community. It is meant to contain features and contributions that eventually should get merged into core TensorFlow, but whose interfaces may still change, or which require some testing to see whether they can find broader acceptance.

The code in tf.contrib isn't supported by the Tensorflow team. It is included in the hope that it is helpful, but it might change or be removed at any time; there are no guarantees.

`tf.research` folder contains machine learning models implemented by researchers in TensorFlow. The models are maintained by their respective authors and have a lower chance of being deprecated.

On the other hand models present directly are officially supported by Tensorflow team and are generally preferred as they have a lower chance of being deprecated in future releases, If you have a model implemented in both, you should generally avoid using the contrib version keeping in mind future compatibility, but the community does do some awesome stuff there, so you might find some models/work not present in the main repository but would be helpful if you used them directly from contrib branch.

Also notice the phrase **generally avoid** since it is a bit application dependent.

Hope that answers your question, comment with your doubts.

Answer (score 1):

With Tensorflow 2.0 (that will come soon) `tf.contrib` will be removed.

Therefore, you **have** to start using `models/research` if you want your project to be up-to-date and still working in the next months.